# Hello! I have problem with recognising all temperature sensors and fan speed sensors, how I can get to recognise all sensors?

Tags: drivers, intel, fan, fancontrol

I apologize for bad english, because is not my primary language.

I decided to install the latest version of Ubuntu 20.04 in my web browsing PC on spare SSD(for transition from Windows 8.1, to not upgrade to Windows 10) in UEFI mode, and it did install succesfully. But after I set up, I notice that   lm-sensors detects only cpu die temps not the motherboard's sensors. Under Windows does detect all sensors with a program called SpeedFan 4.51,with Intel Management Engine driver. I can't found anything about detecting sensors or installing some software to work on this particular motherboard under Ubuntu. It is something that is imposible to do under Ubuntu, or the Intel Management Engine does not work under Linux?

The specs of Web browsing PC:

Motherboard: Intel Desktop Board DG33BU paired with Intel Core 2 Quad Q9550 and 8 GB of DDR2 800

Graphics Card: NVidia GeForce GT 710 1GB

SSD: Adata SU650 120GB

PSU: FSP OEM 320W

I know the the specs aren't great but it works!

[here is a screenshot after it detects "all sensors"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwYYt.png)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Open the command terminal and execute the following command in it:

`sudo apt-get install lm-sensors`

**Step 2:**
To detect the available sensors:

`sudo sensors-detect`

**Step 3:**
To monitor your hardware temperature:

`watch sensors`

Comment: hello! i allready tried that before creating this post, and doesn't recognize the motherboard sensors.